# How can I get the value at the corresponding place while mouseover in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, angularjs, d3.js, javascript-framework

I need to show value at corresponding place while mouseover a line/bar chart using d3.js

```
var toolTip = svg.selectAll("path")
.append("svg:title")
.text(getmouseoverdata(data)
);


function getmouseoverdata(d) {
    return d;
}
```

Here i get all the data in the array while mouseover at any place in the graph.

But I want to show the value at corresponding place. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only looking to display the data elements when you mouseover the path/rect elements, you could try to add the titles directly onto those elements while they are being created?

For example:

```
var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    size = 300;

var canvas = d3.select("body")
               .append("svg:svg")
                    .attr("width", size)
                    .attr("height", size);

var pixels = size / data.length;

canvas.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("svg:rect")
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("height", function(d){return d * pixels})
      .attr("width", pixels/2)
      .attr("x", function(d,i){return i * pixels})
      .attr("y", 0)
      .append("title")    //Adding the title element to the rectangles.
      .text(function(d){return d});
```

This code should create five rectangles with their data element present in a tooltip if you mouseover the rectangle.

Hope this helps.

---

Edit based on comment:

For a bottom to top graph, you can change the y attribute like so:

```
.attr("y", function(d){return size - d * pixels})
```

This addition will cause the bar to start at the difference between the maxHeight of your graph and the size of the bar, effectively turning a top-to-bottom graph into a bottom-to-top graph.

Comment: Thanks chrtan. Its working. The graph is shown from top to bottom. But I want it from bottom to top. Help me..

Comment: @Prince I edited my post to include how to convert a top-to-bottom graph to a bottom-to-top graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can use d3js mouse event handler like this

```
var coordinates = [0, 0];
coordinates = d3.mouse(this);

var x = coordinates[0];
var y = coordinates[1];
```

It will provide you the current mouse coordinates.

Comment: I tried this but getting the following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null (17:39:58:187 | error, javascript)
    at d3_eventSource (http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js:163:17)
    at d3.mouse (http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js:4102:37)

Comment: d3.mouse(this) is a d3.v3.js implementation. I think you need to use d3.svg.mouse(this) for the d3.v2.js.